# How to continue plotting in the same window in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having a problem figuring out how to keep plotting in the same plot window (I want my plots after a single plot to be done in the same window, i.e. I don't want to close the window to get to other plot).Could I use the arrows at the bottom of the plot window to switch to next plot?
Here is my code :

```
for iteration in range(0, max_iters):
    idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids)
    centroids = computeCentroids(X, idx, K)

    if plot is True:
        data = c_[X, idx]
        for i in range(1, K + 1):
            data_1 = data[data[:, n] == i]
            pyplot.plot(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1], linestyle=' ', color=dict[i - 1], marker='o', markersize=3)

        pyplot.plot(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], 'k*', markersize=15)
        pyplot.show(block=True)
        pyplot.hold(True)
```

Here,
**data** is an m**X**n+1 matrix and the nth column has values ranging from 1 to K,
**centroids** is a k**X**n matrix and **idx** is an m**X**1 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use pyplot to draw anything. The only thing it's really good for is creating figures, axes, and some artists.

Without running your example, I do:

```
for iteration in range(0, max_iters):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids)
    centroids = computeCentroids(X, idx, K)

    if plot is True:
        data = c_[X, idx]
        for i in range(1, K + 1):
            data_1 = data[data[:, n] == i]
            ax.plot(data_1[:, 0], data_1[:, 1], linestyle=' ', color=dict[i - 1], marker='o', markersize=3)

        ax.plot(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], 'k*', markersize=15)

    fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But is it possible to plot the resultant plot for each outer loop iteration in the same window? The given code just gives a single (final) plot.

Comment: sure, just move the plot creating into the first loop (I'll edit)

Comment: It did the trick! Thanks! However, the windows all opened without a delay and even closed before I could look at them.

Comment: Hmm, I never look at interactive figures (I just save them to PNGs). What happens if you feed `num=iteration` to `plt.subplots`?

Comment: It worked the same way it did before I added num=iteration to plt.subplots.

Comment: hmm -- does adding `plt.ion()` to the top help?

Comment: It didn't. I think I'll have to study more about interactive plotting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: sorry I couldn't figure that part out for you. in the mean time you can do `fig.savefit('plot_{}.png'.format(iteration), dpi=300)` to save them all as distinct images.